# Add Columns for multiple attributes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, attributes, key-value

I'm really not sure how to explain this, since I just started trying to learn how to use MySQL queries in a more advanced way today. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT pa.displayvalue as Brand
FROM product p
JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1
JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1
JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1
JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1
WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871
AND an.attributeid = 113319;
```

So I have that query, and literally, all I want to do is add another column for the "And an.attributeid = 113319"

I just want to add another column but instead of 113319, I want it to pull the values of let's say 1762 into a column next to it.

So column 1 would have all the values that "And an.attributeid = 113319" pulls, and column two would have all the values that "And an.attributeid = 1762" pulls.

I got this code to work kind of:

```
SELECT pa.displayvalue as Brand
FROM product p
JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1
JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1
JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1
JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1
WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871
AND an.attributeid = 113319;

SELECT pa.displayvalue as Type
FROM product p
JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1
JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1
JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1
JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1
WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871
AND an.attributeid = 1762;
```

But this is returned in navicat as two seperate results. I want both of these to be in one result but as two columns, instead of two results with one column each.

As you can see, all of the lines are the same in each of those Selects except that last line.

I also feel like there is a better way than to have to use that whole code twice just to get another column for an.attributeid. Regardless, I'll take what I can get.

If you have ANY suggestions, I would appreciate it very very much.

Comment: What you're asking is kind of complicated to do, and 99.999999999% of the time not a good idea. Rows are supposed to represent associated pieces of data, not the lines on a page you've drawn some unrelated columns on. When looking for that kind of output, it is best to handle it at the application layer.

Comment: @Uueerdo totally agree. I'd add two ways of handling it at the application level: do two queries and show the results side by side, or do one intermediary query to produce a table containing both results into a single table if the joins are expensive, and then two queries against that table.

Comment: So these numbers that I am trying to change, they are pulling attributes for a product. So that one number will pull the brand name for a bunch of products, and then that other number will pull all the brand types. What I guess I am trying to do is make a CSV that will list the Brand and then the Type. Both are related to each other. So if this were excel, the headers would be: "Brand" and "Type" and then each row would be populated with the brand and type for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that, for formatting or reporting purpose. This is a hack you would use.

And the use of `LEFT JOIN` would return all rows from the left table, with the matching rows in the right table. The result is `NULL` in the right side when there is no match.

```
SELECT p.productid, t2.Type, t1.Brand, t3.Resolution 
FROM product p 
JOIN 
( 
    SELECT p.productid, pa.displayvalue as Brand 
    FROM product p 
    JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1 
    JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1 
    JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1 
    JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1 
    WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871 
    AND an.attributeid = 113319 
) t1 ON t1.productid = p.productid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT p.productid, pa.displayvalue as Type 
    FROM product p 
    JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1 
    JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1 
    JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1 
    JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1 
    WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871 
    AND an.attributeid = 1100 
) t2 ON t2.productid = p.productid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT p.productid, pa.displayvalue as Resolution 
    FROM product p 
    JOIN categoryheader ch ON ch.templatetype = 0 AND p.categoryid=ch.categoryid AND ch.isactive=1 
    JOIN categorydisplayattributes cda ON ch.headerid = cda.headerid AND ch.categoryid = cda.categoryid AND cda.templatetype = ch.templatetype AND cda.isactive=1 
    JOIN productattribute pa ON p.productid = pa.productid AND cda.attributeid = pa.attributeid AND pa.localeid = 1 AND pa.isactive =1 
    JOIN attributenames an ON pa.attributeid = an.attributeid AND an.localeid = 1 
    WHERE p.isactive = 1 AND p.categoryid = 4871 
    AND an.attributeid = 1762 
) t3 ON t3.productid = p.productid
```

Comment: This ends up creating 1mil+ rows of data, however it should only be 27.

Comment: Here I've used a hardcoded key `1` if you're just outputting a single row value. If there're multiple rows, you'd better link the `JOIN` with foreign key. I'm guessing there's a product id you can use.

Comment: @DarkMatter also it'll be better if you could provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: It's actually extremely complicated and I wouldn't really be able to give you sample data since I don't really know EXACTLY how this works. There are so many tables that all pull from each other. I did post a more in depth explanation in my comment on the original question. Maybe that will help? Sorry, just a bit baffled by this.

Comment: Then give it a try, using `product.[primary_key]` in `JOIN` query to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for having minimal knowledge on the subject, but could you sort of tell me exactly where to put that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115909/discussion-between-ydoow-and-darkmatter).

Comment: Hey @ydoow thanks for your help in chat. If you want to take a look at the chat, I ended up using the code you gave me in there, and just making a minor change that worked perfectly.I'd like it if you added that answer to this post so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

`... AND an.attributeid IN (113319, 1762 )`

This would return you two rows with one column.

If you want to transpose rows into columns, then that gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes called a key-value store.  You need to play some games with multiple joins to do what you want.

This sort of thing will do the trick

```
SELECT whatever, 
       attr1.displayvalue attr1,
       attr2.displayvalue attr2
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN productattribute attr1 ON p.productid = attr1.productid
                                  AND attr1.attributeid = 113319
                                  AND attr1.localeid = 1
                                  AND attr1.isactive = 1
  LEFT JOIN productattribute attr2 ON p.productid = attr2.productid
                                  AND attr2.attributeid = 1762
                                  AND attr2.localeid = 1
                                  AND attr2.isactive = 1
```

You end up joining two copies of the attribute table, and selecting the appropriate attribute id from each in the join condition.  You use left join rather than ordinary join so you still get the row even if the attribute is missing.

A very common example in the wild of this data organization is the wp_postmeta table in WordPress.